# Use of Snakemake workflows in AWS Batch

Tags: snakemake, aws-batch

I wanted to ask the Snakemake community if anybody has had success implementing Snakemake workflows in AWS Batch.

Page 4 of a recent publication from Oct 2018 seems to suggest that Snakemake does not work on AWS as it cannot handle resource management. Here is the publication: *Tibanna: software for scalable execution of portable pipelines on the cloud* - https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2019/04/29/440974.full.pdf

Yes, the same paper does suggest the Snakemake works well with the Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

However, the Snakemake documentation  states: "Snakemake 4.0 and later supports execution in the cloud via Kubernetes. This is independent of the cloud provider." - https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#cloud-support

Hence, I would like to know if anyone has implemented Snakemake with AWS Batch.

Also, while on this question, does anyone know of any github/bitbucket page that details the successful implementation of Snakemake with the GCP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

This page details the use of Snakemake with cloud environments like GCP or AWS:

[https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cluster-cloud.html](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cloud.html#executing-a-snakemake-workflow-via-tibanna-on-amazon-web-services)

AWS is actually available via Tibanna.